# Android LocationUpdates not working

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location

I am trying to implement Location Update Listener to detect loction change in android.I have implemented the following code. I get the notification by Log  "GPS Started". But after that the onLocationChanged() function never calls. I tested by changing location but it never called.
Note that GPS is enabbled.

```
public class locationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
LocationManager lManager=null;
TextView _textview;
        void initLocationService()
        {
            {
            lManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

                GpsStatus.Listener gpsListener=new GpsStatus.Listener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
                        if(event==GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED)
                        {
                            Log.e("GPS Listener","GPS Stoped");
                        }
                        else if(event==GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED)
                        {
                            Log.e("GPS Listener","GPS Started");

                        }
                    }
                };

                    LocationRequest lrequest=new LocationRequest();
                lManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsListener);
        }
        }
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Log.e("GPS Listener","LocationChanged");
                     _textview.setText("LocationChanged"+count);
                }
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Log.e("GPS Listener","StatusChanged");
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Log.e("GPS Listener","ProvidedEnabled");
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Log.e("GPS Listener","ProviderDisabled");
                } 


enter code here
                 @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.location_test);
                     _textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                     initLocationService();
                }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    lManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 400, 0,this);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To get location updates, you need to call `requestLocationUpdates()` and give it a `LocationListener`.

Typically, you'd define a [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) with something like:

```
LocationManager locMgr = null;
LocationListener locListener = null;

locListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { } 
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { } 
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
};
```

and enable it in `onResume()` with a call like:

```
locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                              0, // min time in ms
                              0, // min distance in meters
                              locListener);
```

and in `onPause()`:

```
locMgr.removeUpdates(locListener);
```